# reduce and map: how to get the same results

Tags: javascript, reduce, map-function

I am using a `reduce` and my code works correctly, however, I was trying out using a `map`, but not sure how to implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

What does the program do?

> Below I am fetching data from an API for many ids (these are character ids) and then getting the traits related to human characteristics (One characteristic can have many traits) and filtering out `null` traits as I do not want those and then sorting the traits alphabetically. In the end the data structure of the api data should stay the same.

Using `reduce`: (Implementation gets me the correct output)

```
const characteristicsReduce = ids.reduce((acc, id) => (
    {
      ...acc,
      [id]: data?.codes[id]?.traits.filter((trait) => trait !== null).sort((traitOne, traitTwo) => {
        if (traitOne.name < traitTwo.name) return -1;
        if (traitOne.name > traitTwo.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      }),
    }
), {});
```

My output should match:

`{123: Array(20), 456: Array(20)}`

Question 1: How can I write this same code using the `map` function?

Question 2: If the `map` function is successful, which one should be preferred in this scenario, a `map` or a `reduce`, and why?

Comment: You can't even use `map` to do this since this `reduce` call is returning an **object**.

Comment: You can't do it with map. Map produces an array, but you want an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer this: better complexity (avoids spreading the accumulator in each iteration of the reduce) and clearer if one keeps in mind that object entries are `[ [keyA, valueA], [keyB, valueB], ...]`

```
const traitsForID = id => data?.codes[id]?.traits.filter(t => t).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

const entries = ids.map(id => ([id, traitsForID(id)]);
const characteristicsViaMap = Object.fromEntries(entries)
```

Answer (score 3):

While you technically could use `map` like this:

```
const characteristicsReduce = {};

ids.map((id) => {
    characteristicsReduce[id] = data?.codes[id]?.traits.filter((trait) => trait !== null).sort((traitOne, traitTwo) => {
        if (traitOne.name < traitTwo.name) return -1;
        if (traitOne.name > traitTwo.name) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
});
```

You might as well use `forEach` or a regular for-loop. **DO NOT ABUSE MAP LIKE THIS.**

`reduce` is the way to go here since you are trying to reduce an array of ids into one object.

Comment: Hi I tried this code, it gives me an error that an "Arrow function should not return  assignment". But I understand why  reduce needs to be used.

Comment: @myverdict Whoops, I forgot to change one of the closing parentheses to a closing bracket. The arrow function should have a body with that one assignment, nothing else.

Comment: sorry I am asking so many questions, but now I am getting this error "Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function." I tried putting a "return" but still does not work. If I put a "return", it gives the above error "Arrow function should not return assignment".

Comment: @myverdict These aren't even issues with JavaScript. Your editor or linter is already warning you that you are using `map` incorrectly (which is inherently right, this is abusing `map`)...

Comment: So is it safe to say that "map" will not work for the above code??

Comment: @myverdict No, it does... It's just not a good way and you are being warned for it. ***It works***, but it's ***not good***. There is a difference between good code that works and bad code that works.

Comment: Map would be appropriate if used in conjunction with Object.fromEntries()

Comment: @danh That's worth an answer and +1